# iPhone 6 Find my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I bought an iPhone 6 from someone and the phone is still logged into his iCloud and find my iPhone is still on.

I need to reset the phone.

If I restore the phone using the home button and then connect it through my iTunes will it ask me for the the iCloud password of the previous owner?

Comment: All this is true. What is your question?

Comment: if i restore the iphone holding the home and power button and then connect to itunes will it ask me for the previous owner icloud password

Comment: This is the designed behavior. What is your question?

Comment: ask the "someone" u bought the iphone from to remove the device your holding from his account

Comment: it's a brick until the original owner removes the phone from his iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

How to reset a forgotten iPad or iPhone passcode: Never synced with iTunes

If you see one of following alerts, you need to erase your device.

"iTunes could not connect to the [device] because it is locked with a passcode. You must enter your passcode on the [device] before it can be used with iTunes." Or "You haven't chosen to have [device] trust this computer"

If you have enable Find My iPhone (or iPad), use the Remote Wipe feature to erase the contents of your device. Then where possible, use iCloud to restore the most recent backup and reset the passcode.

Note: To use Find My iPhone, you'll need to have set up a restrictions passcode.

If this doesn't work or you don't have access to Find My iPhone or iCloud then follow these steps.

Step one
Place your device in recovery mode. Find out how to do this in our How to get an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch in and out of recovery mode guide.

Step Two:Click 'ok' on the message from iTunes stating the device is in recovery mode.

Step Three:Now restore your device from iTunes.